# How to handle classes that need web resources?

Tags: java, class, exception, httprequest

I'm making a project in Java where I have a class that on its initialization connects to an API to retrieve some info. Based on that info it then provides several methods to use and analyse it.

But what if the web request fails ? Or if I have some other issue. Every method will now fail because they don't have the info required

What I did is having a boolean named loadInfo, and also a public method didLoadInfo, so that the client knows the state of the object. I also add a reloadInfo method to try to reload all info, and every method throws an exception if they are called when the loadInfo variable is false. That exception is a checked exception.

Is there another better way to handle this situation ? The exception thrown by all the methods should be checked or unchecked ?

**EDIT:**

Is a good idea to maintain default values, but how would you let the client know that the info returned may not be up to date ? Maybe another boolean indicating the info state ?

Comment: You're missing the forest for the trees. Look less at your implementation and more at your design. You should have a failsafe in place that doesn't depend on web resources, such as default values from a file, system properties, or from the last session, etc. Whatever you choose, make sure it's something you control.

Comment: @MarsAtomic yours should be the accepted answer, as it provides the right vision rather than a solution.

Comment: Convert all your `throws`, where the data is retrieved and assigned, to `try catches` and supply default values if connection fails or whatever occurs. Definitely not to use boolean flags of whether things have loaded or not.

Comment: You are right, it's a good idea to have default values. But if the info changes frequently, how would you let the client know that the information returned may not be up to date?

Comment: @NicolásVera I would post a warning message to the UI informing the user that the server was unable to retrieve current values, as well as warning of potential consequences. Such a condition is probably worthy of attention from a user, an administrator, or an IT department anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this kind of scenarios you should use REST, so that your java components will be running on web server independently.
If you UI is up and running(it could be on angular or react js or html) and have REST calls in place to call java REST API, also you can configure other API in same web project independent of REST classes and will be initialized as soon at web context is loaded( for example if you are using spring, as soon as application context is loaded).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling other services to retrieve info, use Netflix Hysytix to handle failure gracefully with a fallback method. Obviously, you have many more options to fallback logic.

Check out the official Hystrix Library [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix).

If you have time, check out my article on [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/defend-enterprise-application-from-failing-netflix-hystrix-yojen-rai/).